# How is the type casting happening in R?

Tags: r, casting

```
check.num <- function(x){
  if(x>0){
    print("Greater than or equal to 1")
  } else if(x==0){
    print("Equals zero")
  } else if(x<0){
    print("Less than zero")
  } else{
    print("Confused")
  }
}

check.num(1)
#Output: [1] "Greater than or equal to 1"

check.num(0)
#Output: [1] "Equals zero"

check.num(-1)
#Output: [1] "Less than zero"
```

How are the below commands returning the values? I was expecting '0' in the first case and in the second "Confused" to be returned.

```
check.num("")
#Output: [1] "Less than zero"

check.num("kj")
#Output: [1] "Greater than or equal to 1"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `?Comparison` (or `?">"`):

> If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is
>        coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of
>        precedence being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and
>        raw.

The number 0 is cast to character to match the other argument ("" or "kj"), so we end up with these comparisons:

```
"">"0"   ## FALSE
"kj">"0" ## TRUE
```

that is, it's a *lexicographic* comparison.

Arguably it would be less surprising if a character-vs-numeric comparison gave `NA`, but that's not how the language is defined.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ben Bolker, it solved my problem, and I understand the casting better now. 
I gave a try at the below code to understand the lexicographic comparison.  
if(""<"0") TRUE else FALSE
#Output: [1] TRUE
if("kj">"0") TRUE else FALSE
#Output: [1] TRUE

Comment: if it solves your problem you're encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it (you don't need `if (condition) TRUE else FALSE` ... that just returns the same value as `(condition)`

Comment: Thumbs up. Concise coding practices. Thanks again. :)